# Progress bar by S3 upload

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uwp

I have this code:

```
try
{
    TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(S3AccessId, S3SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

    // Use TransferUtilityUploadRequest to configure options.
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest uploadRequest =
        new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = S3BucketName,
            InputStream = streamx,
            Key = S3FileKey                                              
        };

    uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

    await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
    Debug.WriteLine("Upload completed");


}

catch (AmazonS3Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message, exception.InnerException);


}
```

And I need to update upload progress in generated item in ListView. In this ListView can be multiple items. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do progress Reporting between Distinct lines of code. Usually that means having to disect and replicate the code down to the lowest loop you want to report on. Be that the loop itterating over files or the one itterating over the DataStream.

Only some of the newer classes support deep Progress Reporting. Stuff like [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient) (do not mistake it for System.Net.Http.HttpClient). They have events you can register and then use to do Progress Reporting. I have no idea if this Amazon Library has those capabilities.

Comment: OK, but I need to use AWS SDK because of uploading really big files. Is it possible to pass any variable / object to callback function? I think this part of code: 
uploadRequest.UploadProgressEvent += new EventHandler<UploadProgressArgs>(uploadRequest_UploadPartProgressEvent);

Comment: @Karel_cz: It is a bad idea to transfer anything but inmutable data (numerical types, strings) in Multitasking. You do not want to deal with race conditons caused by multiple pieces of codes using the same instance without Proper Locking. I also learned the hard way that you can not do a lot of writing in Progress Reporting. Writing the GUI is expensive. You can quickly overload the GUI thread with Updates. Anything more then a Integer that is being used to Update a Progress Bar can quickly overload the GUI Thread with Workload.

Comment: OK, if I will update only percent value, how can I know index of actuall item int ListView?